# English translation of Heisenberg's papers

Tags: physics, reference-request, physicists, translations, heisenberg

Strangely, many of Heisenberg's very important scientific papers are not translated into English.

For example, [this one](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007%2FBF01397160) seems not to have been translated.

Where can I get the translated ones?

Comment: http://nonloco-physics.0catch.com/multi.pdf

Comment: There's an [English translation of "Uber den anschaulichen Inhalt derquantentheoretischen Kinematlk und Mechanik", _Zeit-schrift fur Physik_, v. 43, no. 3-4, pp. 172-198, 1927](https://isidore.co/calibre/browse/book/4976).

Comment: Two suggestions.  Firstly, Google Translate has improved dramatically in recent years.  Secondly, if you're feeling adventurous, why not learn enough German to read the papers you need?  If you work in a university, there's probably an in-house team whose job is to facilitate you in learning foreign languages.

Answer (score 2):

It is not strange. They rarely translate papers in physics and mathematics from German or French into English. However two most important papers of Heisenberg and other founders of quantum mechanics are translated in the book
B. L. van der Waerden, Sources on quantum mechanics, (there is a cheap Dover edition).